# ValueError: could not convert string to float: C

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I'm doing a `CSV` I/O program and there is something wrong with it.

```
import csv
filename1 = "sheets2.csv"
filename2 = "newsheet.csv"

fields = ['A','B','C','D','E']

average = 0
total = 0
row_count = 1

with open(filename1,'rU') as csvfile1:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile1)


    with open(filename2,'w') as csvfile2:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile2)

        for col in csvreader:
            csvwriter.writerow(['stas'])
            if len (col[2])>1:
                print("data in col is", "col[4]")
            else:
                print("the data entered is", float(col[2]))
                total = total + int(col[2])
                row_count += 1
average = total/row_count
print(average)
csvwriter.writerow([aver])

csvfile1.close()
csvfile2.close()
```

In `print("the data entered is", float(col[2]))`, the error was:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: C
```

Here is the `CSV` file:

```
A   B   C   D   E
alpha   100 200 300 400
baker   300 500 700 900
cyber   250 340 590 780
dove    320 570 430 220
eggs    670 990 430 570
fish    330 260 870 230
golf    160 320 480 640
halo    280 680 540 320
idom    520 450 670 810
joker   210 240 450 690
```

Comment: Well you obviously don't have a float in `col[2]` as you expect. Try to print it and see what's there...

Comment: @alfasin. Based on the error: `C`

Comment: So should I change float to int to print it?@MadPhysicist   @alfasin

Comment: Can you post your error traceback?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: C  @yklsga

Comment: You won't be able to convert 'C' to an int either. What are you trying to get as output? Do your CSV files contain headers that have the field names?

Comment: You have `C` in your `col[2]` so what are you trying to get done here?

Comment: I just want to add up this column and calculate the average. @yklsga

Comment: Can you post the first 10 lines or so of your CSV?

Comment: You can't calculate average with `string`

Comment: @ConnorCallison  Yes, it has headers and field names.

Comment: @yklsga So I have a string(maybe the headers) in my sum?

Comment: A B C D Ealpha 100 200 300 400
baker 300 500 700 900
cyber 250 340 590 780
dove 320 570 430 220
eggs 670 990 430 570
fish 330 260 870 230
golf 160 320 480 640
halo 280 680 540 320
idom 520 450 670 810
joker 210 240 450 690 Emm... I don't know how to make it in a table. There's 5column and 11rows....

Comment: Please post the csv lines in the original question and format it @Haochen

Comment: Oh, I see. @yklsga

Comment: @Haochen may be, not sure

Comment: @yklsga I've posted it.

Comment: I finally found out why I get the error message. In the first "if", it should be  "if len(col[2]) =1". Thank you very much for your help. @yklsga

Comment: @Haochen do you mean `if len(col[2]) == 1` ? even then you will get an error. because col is a list with a length of 1. So you will get a index out of range error

Comment: @yklsga Yes. Because the heading row is "A B C D E" and I have 5 columns, so the length of each is one. I use <= in my codes and it works.

Comment: @yklsga and only C has the length of 1, so the rest data is collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, we are adding an if check to see if the column is not a number, which would indicate that it is a header.

We can test if the value is a number or not before attempting to sum it.
(Revision)

```
import csv
filename1 = "sheets2.csv"
filename2 = "newsheet.csv"

fields = ['A','B','C','D','E']

average = 0
total = 0
row_count = 1

with open(filename1,'rU') as csvfile1:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile1)


    with open(filename2,'w') as csvfile2:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile2)

        for col in csvreader:
            csvwriter.writerow(['stas'])
            if len (col[2])>1:
                print("data in col is", "col[4]")
            else:
                print("the data entered is", str(col[2]))
                if col[2].isdigit():
                    total = total + int(col[2])
                    row_count += 1
                else:
                    print("String column, value:",col[2])

average = total/row_count
print(average)
csvwriter.writerow([aver])

csvfile1.close()
csvfile2.close()
```

Comment: I tried it but it still included the heading"C"(you can refer to my question), so maybe there's some way to jump over the first row but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: The error message was "ValueError: could not convert string to float: C".

Comment: In  "print("the data entered is", float(col[2]))"

Comment: Revised to use the isdigit() function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: Oh. I know what I did wrong. Thank you very much for helping me, Connor. I really appreciate it. @ConnorCallison

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help!